# Communicate with Roomba 871

Tags: roomba

I have a *Roomba 871* and I am trying to communicate with it through the sci port.
I am using `RealmTerm` for testing, I am trying it with the [How to Program Roomba - RealTerm Terminal](http://www.robotappstore.com/Knowledge-Base/How-to-Use-a-RealTerm-Terminal/16.html) guide.

If I try it with a baud rate of *57600* the only thing I am able to is to get the Roomba to perform an spot cleaning. To get to that the only thing I have to do is to send it an value of `130-139, 230-239, 330-33`... But I have to send it as ASCII not as Numbers, like mentioned in the description above.

If I try it with a baud rate of *115200* the only thing I am able to do is to switch it off. But then it is switched off until I lift the Roomba up. Pushing the Power button does noting in that case. To switch it off I send the numbers like in the description above: `140 0 1 62 32`  but send as numbers!

So this is quite strange and I really don't know what to do, so please help.

Answer (score 1):

The right baud rate is 115200. If you did not changed it.

You need to send decimalcodes:

`128` to start the interface.

`135` to start or stop cleaning.

Try `128 135` at first.

Please refer to [iRobot® Create® 2 Open Interface (OI) Specification](https://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf)

Here you find HTerm with roomba commands: [https://static.vvcc.de/roomba/hterm_roomba.zip](http://static.vvcc.de/roomba/hterm_roomba.zip). Maybe it helps you. Just drag and drop `roomba.cfg` to `HTerm.exe`. No installation needed.

Comment: I tried to send 128 135 with RealTerm. I've pressed the button send numbers, so it should be right or? But nothing happens....

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally created two accounts (Binkowski & ChristianBinkowski). Stack Exchange only allows an individual to actively use one account, so please follow the instructions at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)
Note that moderators [can't merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272251) for you, but may delete accounts they believe to be [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/138432).